# Wordpress drop-down-menu only on one page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, drop-down-menu

I want to create a drop-down-menu on a wordpress page but only in one page.
Is there a way or a **plugin** to create drop-down-menu directly from the editor page without writing HTML/CSS or creating a custom-telmplate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this wordpress plugins:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/